# Jasmine httpBackend-related tests broken when upgrading Angular 2.21 to 2.25

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have many tests in Jasmine and Karma that rely on $httpBackend HTTP mocking checks. When I upgrdaded Angular today, they stopped to work.

Suppose I have something like this inside my Jasmine test:

```
    // Arrange
    httpBackend.expect('POST', 'https://localhost:44300/api/projects/1/samples').respond(fakedDto);
    // Act
    scope.updateSamples();
    httpBackend.flush();
```

and on the last line, that was perfectly ok before, I receive:

```
    TypeError: $browser.$$checkUrlChange is not a function in C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js (line 12502)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12502:9
createHttpBackendMock/$httpBackend.flush@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1481:5
@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/tests/integration/sample/samplecreationController_integration.test.js:341:9
```

Moreover, I have usual configuration to wrap up tests:

```
afterEach(function () {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

that now started to generate the following error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest in C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js (line 78)
minErr/<@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:5
beginPhase@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13009:9
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12500:9
createHttpBackendMock/$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1514:5
@C:/SVN/samplemgmt/src/ClientApp/tests/integration/sample/samplecreationController_integration.test.js:137:9
```

I appreciate some suggestions how to make things work again. Are there any changes made to httpBackend testing lately?

Comment: I have a similar problem with httpBackend.flush() and $scope.$apply(). I don't get '$digest already in progress', but I do get 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' when I call either of the above angular methods inside jasmine tests in 1.2.25 but not in Angular 1.2.22.

Comment: Can you post a little more about your test? The error "$digest already in progress" is happening if you call a $scope.$apply on the wrong place. First, it seems that you test is ok, maybe a mistake in your tested code?

Comment: The problem I think is that the version of angular-mocks has to be the same than angular, so did you upgraded angular-mocks as well ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917099/browser-checkurlchange-is-undefined-in-a-jasmine-test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who are stuck with old Angular and can't upgrade at this point for some reason, [here](http://nikas.praninskas.com/angular/2015/11/20/quickie-httpbackend-digest-in-progress/) is a great post that explains what's going on and how to solve the problem.

To summarize -

The issue happens because both `$httpBackend.flush()` and `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` mistakenly try to do digest. Obviously, the inner one (from `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` call) fails. Luckily, we can instruct it not to perform digest - note the `false` parameter:

```
afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation(false); // <-- here
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Angular-Mocks had to be updated manually (not using bower..) at that point.