# $browser.$$checkUrlChange is undefined in a jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following test:

```
it('should maintain a bind between the data at the $scope to the data at the ingredientsService', function(){
    $scope.addFilters('val1', $scope.customFiltersData, 'filter1');
    $scope.$digest();
    expect($scope.customFiltersData).toEqual(ingredientsService.filters());
});
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$digest (/home/oleg/dev/vita-webapp-new/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12502:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/oleg/dev/vita-webapp-new/test/spec/controllers/customfilters.js:92:20)
```

When debugging I saw that `$browser.$$checkUrlChange` on line `12502` of `angular.js` is indeed undefined.

As a temporary solution, I changed the invocation on line `1250` to `$browser.$$checkUrlChange && $browser.$$checkUrlChange()`

But I cannot help to wonder whether this monkey-patch can hurt me in some other way.

Any clue on how to solve this properly is much appreciated.

In case I do not get my answers I might consider opening a bug at the Angular repo on GitHub.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jasmine test fails with undefined is not a function(evaluating $browser.$$checkUrlChange())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785149/jasmine-test-fails-with-undefined-is-not-a-functionevaluating-browser-checku)

Comment: You should post your answer, sir :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a mismatch in the version of angular and angular-mock .
See here:

[jasmine test fails with undefined is not a function(evaluating $browser.$$checkUrlChange())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785149/jasmine-test-fails-with-undefined-is-not-a-functionevaluating-browser-checku)